# How to bind HTML table using SOAP Response

Tags: javascript, soap, html-table, dynamics-crm-2011

I am fetching data using SOAP in C#.
This is the SOAP response I am getting.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<GetApplicantInfoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<GetApplicantInfoResult xmlns:a="http://*****.*****.org/****/*******.Data" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:DateOfBirth></a:DateOfBirth>
<a:Email></a:Email>
<a:FirstName></a:FirstName>
</GetApplicantInfoResult></GetApplicantInfoResponse>
</s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Which is then retrieved  using a **`JavaScript`** call on **`.html`**

Now need to bind the data to the **`HTML Table`**.

Comment: One solution i found was to use XML to bind it.Please suggest possible conversion of SOAP response to XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [XML Parser](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp) then JavaScript to add data into the table.

```js
function getSoap() {
  return '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
    '<s:Body>' +
    '<GetApplicantInfoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">' +
    '<GetApplicantInfoResult xmlns:a="http://*****.*****.org/****/*******.Data" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">' +
    '<a:DateOfBirth></a:DateOfBirth>' +
    '<a:Email>james@email.com</a:Email>' +
    '<a:FirstName>James</a:FirstName>' +
    '</GetApplicantInfoResult></GetApplicantInfoResponse>' +
    '</s:Body></s:Envelope>';
}

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(getSoap(), "text/xml");

document.getElementById("firstname").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a:FirstName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a:FirstName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

```html
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="firstname"></td>
    <td id="email"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```